# VBA code is printing report instead of opening it

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a button on a form that should open a report but it sending the report to the default printer instead. How do stop it from printing? I'm using access 2010

```
Private Sub Generate_Click()
    If Me.Staff = "<< All >>" Then
        DoCmd.OpenReport "rptAll", acViewNormal, , , acHidden
    Else
        DoCmd.OpenReport "rptStaff", acViewNormal, , , acHidden
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Use `acViewLayout`, `acViewReport` or `acViewPreview`. But why are you hiding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use acViewReport as stated here in the MSDN doc if you want to show the report.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195735%28v=office.15%29.aspx